# Double integral of $3y$ over an annular sector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Evaluate $\int\int_D 3y dA$, where $D$ is the first quadrant region between the circles of radius $1$ and radius $2$.

I have no clue how to solve this, the farthest I was able to parse from this question is getting: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^2$ Because it's in the first quadrant, but that's as far I as I can get for now. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also, please don't give me the answer if it's at all possible.

Comment: You're on the right track; when you write $\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_1^2$ you've parameterized the region using $\theta$ and $r$. Now you need to write $3y$ in terms of those variables and note that $dA = r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: what would by r? 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. You've parameterized your integral so that you can integrate with respect to $r$ and with respect to $\theta$. Because the region over which you're integrating is the area between circles of radius 1 and 2, the natural bounds of the integral over $r$ are $1$ *and* $2$.

Comment: I'm just confused at this step. Write 3y in terms of r and θ and note that dA=rdrdθ.

Comment: I'd read over [this site](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/dipolarcoords.aspx)

Comment: oh ok, thanks clears up. Thanks